# Can I ask a question "What game is this" on, for example, Arqade network?

Tags: support, questions

I'd like to know if I can ask questions about "What game is this" on [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/) network (or similar StackExchange website). Last time I described a game in a decent deal of detail (no screenshot) I got my thread deleted/archieved. Did the rules change since then?

I know I can ask about books, or movies without posting their content in some way shape or form. Not exactly sure why I can ask about this kind of entertainment media, but not gaming kind of entertainment media. Considering some games' focus on the story, these are really similar sometimes

---

If the screenshot is the requirement here, then it is kind of pointless as most of the time (in my case) when I have the screenshot, I have the game name too. For example screenshot can come from a particular internet address which has game name in name, or an article, or a file in folder named like the game etc.

Comment: There is a whole dedicated section for this in the Arquade help: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic You can ask for identification but must meet their criteria. I suggest you ask on https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/ for a clarification on those rules. Consider reading all of these first https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-identification

Comment: If the rules on that  SE site bothers you too much, do try this advice: https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10197/what-are-the-requirements-for-asking-a-game-identification-question#comment44324_10198

Comment: Possible duplicate (but I don't want to hammer it): [Are identify-this questions allowed on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76005/295232) That question is more general but Arqade/Gaming is mentioned as a prime example. Otherwise, it might be better off at Gaming.Meta.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Identifying a game *might* be appropriate on the Arqade network.
The tag [description](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/game-identification/info) for [game-identification](/questions/tagged/game-identification) outlines what criteria your question must meet.

The tag excerpt state the following:

> USE WITH CAUTION: Only ask if you have a screenshot, video, or audio
>   clip from the game you want to identify. This tag is only for
>   identifying games in movies, pictures, videos, advertisements or
>   otherwise where an unknown game appears - not from a description of
>   what you can recall from memory, or from a picture you drew yourself.

Furthermore their site has an excellent [FAQ entry](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10197/what-are-the-requirements-for-asking-a-game-identification-question) on these types of questions:

Comment: Accurate, but renders game-identification fairly useless as a tag (and, imo, cripples most of the value of that particular substack).